# Rails + CanCan: Disallow User from Joining a Group if Already a Member

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, cancan, cancancan

I have a Rails app, using CanCan for authorization. I have Users that can have Memberships in Groups. I would like to create a CanCan rule that authorizes a user to create a group membership only if they are not already a member of that group. So far I have been unable to figure out the magic:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :members, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :member, class_name: 'User'
  belongs_to :group
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships
  has_many :memberships, foreign_key: 'member_id'
end

class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)

    user ||= User.new

    # One of my sad attempts...
    can :create, Membership do |membership|
      !membership.group.has_member(user)
    end

  end

end

<% if can? :create, Membership %>
   View code for creating memberships...
<% end %>
```

Your assistnace is appreciated. Also, I do understand that CanCanCan is the successor of CanCan. A CanCanCan answer will be fine.

Comment: From this [wiki](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#hash-of-conditions) you may want to try ````can :create, Membership, Membership do |membership|````

Comment: If you have an example that will work that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CanCan blocks only work on model instances (see [this wiki page](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks)) and right now your `can?` sends the model class, not an instance.

In order for this to work, you need to pass an instance of Membership. You can do something like this (assuming @group is the group the user wants to join)

```erb
<% if can? :create, Membership.new(group: @group) %>
   View code for creating memberships...
<% end %>
```

I would recommend, however, that you put the ability on the group. In my opinion, it is a more direct approach.

**ability.rb**

```ruby
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new

    can :join, Group do |group|
      !group.members.include?(user)
    end
  end
end
```

**View**

```erb
<% if can? :join, @group %>
   View code for creating memberships...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Your first answer does not work for me - perhaps a conflict with other rules I have defined. Your second, preferred, answer does the trick!

Comment: I'm thinking the second answer can be gotten around by a savvy user and an HTTP client though. I think I need to get your first answer working to protect against that. UPDATE: got it working.